# SearchBar Pass Data to Screen

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I search and get the information from the api and you can see that it shows in the log, now I want this new information to replace the old information. How do I do this?

u see in my code

my fun MainScreen

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

    SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
            color = Color(0, 119, 182)
        )
    }



    val weather = produceState<DataOrException<Weather, Boolean, Exception>>(
        initialValue = DataOrException(loading = true)
    ) {
        value = mainViewModel.weather(city = "Tehran")
    }.value

    if (weather.loading == true) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    } else if (weather.data != null) {
        MainScaffold(
            data = weather.data!!,
            navController = navController,
            mainViewModel = mainViewModel,
        )
    }
}
```

fu  MainScaffold

```
@Composable
fun MainScaffold(
    data: Weather, navController: NavController, mainViewModel: MainViewModel,
) {
    val searchState by mainViewModel.searchState
    val searchTextState by mainViewModel.searchTextState
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        MainAppBar(
            searchState = searchState,
            searchTextState = searchTextState,
            onTextChange = { mainViewModel.updateSearchTextState(newValue = it) },
            onCloseClicked = { mainViewModel.updateSearchState(newValue = SearchState.CLOSED) },
            onSearchClicked = {
                Log.d("Search Text", it)
                
            },
            onSearchTriggered = {
                mainViewModel.updateSearchState(newValue = SearchState.OPENED)
            },
            data = data, navController = navController
        )
    }) {
            MainContent(navController = navController, data = data)
    }
```

and my fun MainAppbar

```
@Composable
fun MainAppBar(
    searchState: SearchState,
    searchTextState: String,
    onTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onCloseClicked: () -> Unit,
    onSearchClicked: (String) -> Unit,
    onSearchTriggered: () -> Unit,
    data: Weather,
    navController: NavController,
) {
    when (searchState) {
        SearchState.CLOSED -> {
            AppBar(
                title = data.location.name + ", ${data.location.country}",
                navController = navController,
                color = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color(
                        0,
                        119,
                        182
                    )
                ),
                onSearchClicked = onSearchTriggered
            )
        }
        SearchState.OPENED -> {
            SearchAppBar(
                text = searchTextState,
                onTextChange = onTextChange,
                onCloseClick = onCloseClicked,
                onSearchClick = onSearchClicked,
            )
        }
    }
}

}
```

okey this my code ...

here

```
onSearchClicked = {
                Log.d("Search Text", it)
            }
```

i have one text .
When I write any word in the search field, it shows me here. And I correctly see that word in the log... Now I want this word to this part

```
val weather = produceState<DataOrException<Weather, Boolean, Exception>>(
         initialValue = DataOrException(loading = true)
     ) {
         value = mainViewModel.weather(city = "Tehran")
    }.value
```

which is written in MainScreen, but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone guide me now?

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code. Paste the relevant snippets and log output in the question instead.

Comment: @lee-m okey bro now u can see my code . Please help me, I have been dealing with this problem for several days